# Clojure: core: splitting load-file into two steps

Tags: clojure

### Question

Is it possible to split load-file into two steps:

```
(1) compile and
(2) load ?
```

### Context

I'm doing hot code reloading to a *remote* machine. I don't want to ship the source over to the machine, then thane the machine load-file it. Instead, I want to ship a *.class file over to the machine, and have the machine just reload the namespace with the *.class

Thus, I want a way to:

```
(1) transform *.clj files to *.class files that can be hot-reloaded
```

and

```
(2) I need to be able to call remove-ns on them later (when they have to be replaced)
```

### EDIT

I'm also perfectly happy using (require :reload ... ) -- again, as long as I can just provide it a *.class file instead of my *.clj files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

1. On your local machine, use [compile](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/compile) to compile your clojure source into .class files.
2. Upload those to your remote server.
3. Use [require](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/require) to (re)load the namespaces.

In your source code, you should rely on `require` instead or `load-file`, specifically for this reason. At runtime, you can't be sure whether the namespaces will come from a source file, a compiled binary.